# I am trying to send mail in python using shell command . But variable does not get substituted in script

Tags: python, bash, email, subprocess

```
import subprocess
to ='xxxx@fmr.com'
subject= 'hostname'
cmd= "cat /var/log | mailx -s 'swap is full on'+subject" +to
subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
```

## if i place double quote before subject then mailx takes first character as subject and treat other as the recipient and try to send mail to them .

## --------------------out put of   cmd= "cat /var/log | mailx -s 'swap is full on'"+subject +to

Comment: *cat /var/log* does not work, since */var/log* is a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
import subprocess
to ='xxxx@fmr.com'
cmd= "cat /var/log | mailx -s 'test' " + to
subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
```